# How to make stow ignore DS_Store files

Tags: macos, stow

I'm using GNU stow to manage my dotfiles, on a Mac.

I tried creating a `.stow-local-ignore` file in the root stow directory, with the contents:

```
\.DS_Store
```

But I still get errors:

```
WARNING! stowing bin would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .DS_Store
All operations aborted.
```

How do I configure `stow` to always ignore all `.DS_Store` files?

Answer (score 2):

To ignore all `.DS_Store` files,
you need to add

```
\.DS_Store
```

to `~/.stow-global-ignore` (under your home directory).

---

`.stow-local-ignore` only applies
to specific packages (subfolders) in your root `stow` directory.
From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Ignore-Lists):

> If you put Perl regular expressions, one per line, in a .stow-local-ignore file **within any top level package directory**, in which case any file or directory **within that package** matching any of these regular expressions will be ignored.

For example,
say you have two packages,
`foo` and `bar`, in your root `stow` directory.
You run `stow foo` and `stow bar`.

```
root-dir
|-- .stow-local-ignore      # STOW ignores this file since it's not associated with any package.
|-- foo
|   └-- .stow-local-ignore  # STOW uses this file since it's in a package.
└-- bar
```

Note that `.stow-local-ignore` overwrites `.stow-global-ignore`,
so if you use a local ignore file,
make sure to add

```
\.DS_Store
```

to it as well.